# How can I create a Feature and have it saved under 'features manage' tab?

Tags: features

I see that I can create a Feature, but the only option is to download it. Is there a way I can just have Drupal import it to the manage tab of Features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Direct save" feature of the [Features Tools](http://drupal.org/project/ftools) module if you want to do this from the UI instead of the command line with Drush.

Comment: didn't know about that module!

Comment: Did not know about this module either. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you copy the downloaded Feature to your /sites/all/modules folder it will show up under Manage Features in the UI. If you're using Drush, then when you run `features-export` it will export the code to your /sites/all/modules folder, bypassing the download step. However, I've found that creating the Feature in the UI is easier than creating it from scratch with Drush. So I'd recommend just sticking with the UI and copying the downloaded code. Once it's been created, the `features-update` Drush command is the easiest way to update the Feature with any changes you've made to it's components.